# Proof verification for L is not context-free

Tags: proof-verification, formal-languages, automata

Prove that $L = \small\{ ww | w \in (0, 1)^* \small\}$ is $\textbf{not}$ a context-free language.

Assume $L$ is a context free language. 
Let $s = 1^p0^p1^p0^p$ where clearly $|s| \geq p$ and $s \in L\:$and $s =uvxy$
The exhaustive ways to build $vxy$ are:

1) contains $1$'s (first or second half)
Considering $|vy|>0$ then either $v$ or $y$ contains at least one 1. Let $i = 0 \:$ $s' = uv^0xy^0z$ will have at least one missing 1. $s'$ is either for first-half $1^{p-1}0^p1^p0^p$ or $1^p0^p1^{p-1}0^p$ for second-half neither of which is $\in L$

2) contains $0$'s (first or second half)
Considering $|vy|>0$ then either $v$ or $y$ contains at least one 0. Let $i = 0 \:$ $s' = uv^0xy^0z$ will have at least one missing 0. $s'$ is either for first-half $1^p0^{p-1}1^p0^p$ or $1^p0^p1^p0^{p-1}$ for second-half neither of which is $\in L$

3)contains 1's and 0's (first or second half)
Consider $|vy|>0$ then $v$ or $y$ must contain at least one 1 or 0 or be a mix of them. Let  $i = 2 \:$ $s' = uv^2xy^2z$ will have at least one extra 1 or 0.

For first-half: 
$s' = 1^{p+x}0^p1^p0^p$ $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$ 
$s' = 1^p0^{p+x}1^p0^p$ $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$ 
$s' = 1^{p+x}0^{p+y}1^p0^p$ $x + y > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$

For second-half: 
$s' = 1^p0^p1^{p+x}0^p$ $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$ 
$s' = 1^p0^p1^p0^{p+x}$ $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$ 
$s' = 1^p0^p1^{p+x}0^{p+y}$ $x + y > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$

4)contains $0$'s and $1$'s in the middle
Considering $|vy|>0$ then either $v$ or $y$ contains at least one 0 or 1 or is a mix of them. Let $i = 0 \:$ $s' =  uv^0xy^0z$ will have at least one 0 or 1 missing.

Cases: 
$s' = 1^p0^{p-x}1^p0^p$ $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$
$s' = 1^p0^p0^{p-x}0^p$  $x > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$
$s' = 1^p0^{p-x}1^{p-y}0^p$ $x + y > 0$ clearly $s' \notin L$ even if $x = y$ so that number of removed $0$'s and $1$'s are same then $num(first\: consecutive \: 1's)$ > $num(second\: consecutive \:1's)$ clearly $s' \notin L$

No matter what decomposition we choose for $1^p0^p1^p0^p$ for each one there is an $i$ such that $s' = uv^ixy^iz \notin L$. Therefore L is not a context-free-language.

Can someone please check whether my proof is correct or whether I've missed any case? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you consider a subset of language $L$ given by all elements of the form $s$. This would not be sufficient, since e.g.. the language $a^*b^*$ is regular but $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq0\}$ is a subset which is not regular.

Comment: The intersection of a context-free language with regular language is a context-free language. If I can find an intersection that is not a context-free language then $L$ is also not context-free. $ \small\{ww| w \in {0,1}^*\small\} \cap \small\{ 1^*0^*1^*0^*\small\} = \small\{1^p0^p1^p0^p\small\}$ I show that "1^p0^p1^p0^p" is not context-free therefore $L$ is also not context-free. Where's the mistake in that?

Comment: @MetaXenology $110110$ is of the form $ww$ and belongs to $1^*0^*1^*0^*$. However, it is not of the form $1^p0^p1^p0^p$;